# I tried to install playonlinux and after that I had trouble opening Ubuntu software center and updates manager i can't open it

Tags: 12.04, software-center, update-manager, playonlinux

This is what update manager shows me when I open it:

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information. Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message: 
  E:Type '--2015-01-11' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list

--2015-01-11 18:00:40--  http://deb.playonlinux/playonlinux?trusty.list
Connecting to 147.91.1.42:8080... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2015-01-11 18:01:45--  (try: 2)  http://deb.playonlinux/playonlinux?trusty.list
Connecting to 147.91.1.42:8080... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2015-01-11 18:02:50--  (try: 3)  http://deb.playonlinux/playonlinux?trusty.list
Connecting to 147.91.1.42:8080... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2015-01-11 18:03:56--  (try: 4)  http://deb.playonlinux/playonlinux?trusty.list
Connecting to 147.91.1.42:8080... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2015-01-11 18:05:03--  (try: 5)  http://deb.playonlinux/playonlinux?trusty.list
Connecting to 147.91.1.42:8080... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2015-01-11 18:06:11--  (try: 6)  http://deb.playonlinux/playonlinux?trusty.list
Connecting to 147.91.1.42:8080... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2015-01-11 18:07:20--  (try: 7)  http://deb.playonlinux/playonlinux?trusty.list
Connecting to 147.91.1.42:8080... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2015-01-11 18:08:30--  (try: 8)  http://deb.playonlinux/playonlinux?trusty.list
Connecting to 147.91.1.42:8080... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2015-01-11 18:09:41--  (try: 9)  http://deb.playonlinux/playonlinux?trusty.list
Connecting to 147.91.1.42:8080... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2015-01-11 18:10:54--  (try:10)  http://deb.playonlinux/playonlinux?trusty.list
Connecting to 147.91.1.42:8080... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2015-01-11 18:12:07--  (try:11)  http://deb.playonlinux/playonlinux?trusty.list
Connecting to 147.91.1.42:8080... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2015-01-11 18:13:20--  (try:12)  http://deb.playonlinux/playonlinux?trusty.list
Connecting to 147.91.1.42:8080... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2015-01-11 18:14:33--  (try:13)  http://deb.playonlinux/playonlinux?trusty.list
Connecting to 147.91.1.42:8080...
```

Comment: It seems there is something wrong with a configuration file. Please post the contents of the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list`

Comment: Sorry i am new here... how can i do that??

Comment: @Dusan: Open the file in a text editor like GEdit and copy its content into the clipboard. [edit] your question, paste the clipboard content into the text area and format is as a “code sample” (tool bar button with the `<$>` icon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest deleting the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list` - it's not a valid apt sources.list formatted file.

Comment: how i can do that?? :D

Comment: `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list`